# How to draw a String using Graphics2D class?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Greeting, I am working on a simple application to get video feedback from drone. So here is my problem. I have no idea why I cannot show the string words "No video connection" to my panel. Any idea what is happening here? When I run this frame, it just show me a plain empty frame without anything. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
package dronetest;

import com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import javax.swing.*;

public class testStringVideo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private AtomicReference<BufferedImage> image = new AtomicReference<BufferedImage>();
    private AtomicBoolean preserveAspect = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private BufferedImage noConnection = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    /**
     * Creates new form testStringVideo
     */
    public testStringVideo() {
        initComponents();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) noConnection.getGraphics();
        Font f = g2d.getFont().deriveFont(24.0f);
        System.err.println(f);

        g2d.drawString("No video connection", 40, 100); 
        image.set(noConnection);
        System.err.println(image);
    }

    public void setDrone(ARDrone drone) {
        drone.addImageListener(this);
    }

    public void setPreserveAspect(boolean preserve) {
        preserveAspect.set(preserve);
    }

    public void frameReceived(BufferedImage im) {
        image.set(im);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        drawDroneImage(g2d, width, height);
    }

    private void drawDroneImage(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage im = image.get();
        if (im == null) {
            return;
        }
        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;
        if (preserveAspect.get()) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fill3DRect(0, 0, width, height, false);
            float widthUnit = ((float) width / 4.0f);
            float heightAspect = (float) height / widthUnit;
            float heightUnit = ((float) height / 3.0f);
            float widthAspect = (float) width / heightUnit;

            if (widthAspect > 4) {
                xPos = (int) (width - (heightUnit * 4)) / 2;
                width = (int) (heightUnit * 4);
            } else if (heightAspect > 3) {
                yPos = (int) (height - (widthUnit * 3)) / 2;
                height = (int) (widthUnit * 3);
            }
        }
        if (im != null) {
            g2d.drawImage(im, xPos, yPos, width, height, null);
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testStringVideo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testStringVideo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testStringVideo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testStringVideo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new testStringVideo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You'll want to call super.paintComponent

Comment: Hi Shrey, may I know where should I call super.paintComponent? Sorry as I quite new to this. Thanks.

Comment: It's standard to name classes with capital camel case, i.e. `TestStringVideo`.  You make it harder for yourself and others to read your code when you don't follow expected naming conventions.

Comment: Since you are implementing your own paintComponent method, youll want to call super.paintComponent() as the first line in that method (and then have your own implementation). Calling super will go to the parent class (the JPanel) and call the method paintcomponent within it. This is just good practice, not sure if it will actually help fix the problem you have but I believe the answers below can!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you do not call `getGraphics()` directly:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) noConnection.getGraphics();
```

this gives you a pointer to the `Graphics` object, but not while the window is being drawn.

Instead, you should override the `paintComponent()` method of an inner `JLabel`, like [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) demonstrates (notice the `super.paintComponent()` call that others were suggesting).

> ```
> public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
>   super.paintComponent(g);       
>
>   // Draw Text
>   g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
> }
> ```

The `paintComponent()` method is called by the Swing [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and passed a `Graphics` instance when Swing is ready to paint that component.

There's a number of useful tutorials on Oracle's site (as well as elsewhere) that go into more detail:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Overview of the Java 2D API Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html)
- [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Be sure to read through these; Swing does a lot of work behind the scenes for you.  It saves you a lot of time, but if you don't understand what it's doing you'll be fighting against it instead of letting it work with you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Java 2D, but an alternative would be to create a `JTextArea` and add it to `testStringVideo`. If you are interested in how to do so, here are some general instructions:

1. Declare member variable `JTextArea connectionMessage;`
2. Initiate it: `connectionMessage = new JTextArea("No video connection");`
3. create a method that adds `connectionMessage` to `testStringVideo` when it needs to

Let me know if this works or if you still need help!